# How do I output which points from the original point cloud are included in the coordinates of each voxel grid open3d?

Tags: python, open3d

```py
voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size)
```

I want to know which points are contained in each voxel grid, and how to print them.